# what is wrong with my quick sort ? inplace and random

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I know this is a very popular topic but I really cant find my problem(s) here.

```
import random

class QuickSort(object):
    def _choose_pivot(self,l,r):
        return random.sample(range(l,r),1)[0]

    def _partition(self,arr,l,r):
        pivot_idx = self._choose_pivot(l, r) #random pivot
        #move the pivot to the end 
        pivot =  arr[pivot_idx]
        temp =  arr[r-1]
        arr[r-1] = arr[pivot_idx] 
        arr[pivot_idx] = temp
        print arr
        i = l
        for j in range(l,r-1):
            if arr[j]<=pivot:
                temp = arr[j]
                arr[j] = arr[i]
                arr[i] = temp
                i+=1
        #put pivot in its place
        temp = arr[i]
        arr[i] = arr[r-1]
        arr[r-1] = temp
        return i

    def sort(self,arr,l,r):
        if len(arr) <= 1:
            return arr
        if r-l<=2:
            return arr
        pivot_idx = self._partition(arr, l , r)
        self.sort(arr, pivot_idx+1 , r)
        self.sort(arr, l , pivot_idx-1)
        return arr
```

for example for input a = [8,5,6,2,1,0,4,3] it returns [1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 8]. it seems there is a problem with my recursive calls to base case. it doesn't call the sort function for every partition:so here the steps:

```
pivot 2
[8, 5, 6, 3, 1, 0, 4, 2]

[1, 5, 6, 3, 8, 0, 4, 2]

[1, 0, 6, 3, 8, 5, 4, 2]

pivot 8
[1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 8]

[1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 8]

[1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 8]

[1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 8]

[1, 0, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 8]

pivot 3
[1, 0, 2, 5, 6, 3, 4, 8]

pivot 6
[1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 8]

[1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 4, 8]
```

Comment: Contrary to popular belief, Stack Overflow is not a debugging service. You do need to do some work up front yourself. For example, you need to tell us what your code is supposed to do, what you expect to happen and where you think the problem may lie. Also see [Are there legitimate "fix my code" questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/253787) and the linked [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog post.

Comment: What results do you get?

Comment: What you *don't* do is just dump the code and only say 'what is wrong'.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Since it is a well known problem I didn't find it necessary to explain what should be the output but you are right about the problem part. so I updated my question. be sure that I spend enough time before posting it here.

Comment: @Moj: now we are getting somewhere. You've shown input, the output produced and some attempts to debug the problem. That's a whole lot better than just a code dump.

Comment: Why the `random.sample()` when a `random.randrange()` call is so much simpler?

Comment: @MartijnPieters just a habit since I usually using `sample` for getting more than one random element.

Comment: Why do you use temp variables when swapping values? It might be clearer using the python syntax `a, b = b, a`.

Comment: @user189 can't make use of it. I don't know why! can you direct me to an example?

Comment: Maybe this will help http://forums.udacity.com/questions/2015081/swap-values-in-python-problem-set-1-q-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you use the Python range notation: in range(l, r), l is included, r is not.

Hence, the partition of your array is the following: `arr[l:pivot_idx] + [arr[pivot_idx]] + arr[pivot_idx+1:r]`.

So I think the error would be solved by using the following line: `self.sort(arr, l , pivot_idx)`.

Moreover, there is only one element in an array iff `r-l<=1`.